# using an image for a button on php

Tags: php, html, button, open-source

I have a php script which creates its own button, as I am using an open source framework. What I want is to use an image to create a button instead of a the link the is created. Here is the line for which I need the button:

```
<td class="main button_marg"><?php echo tep_draw_button(IMAGE_BUTTON_REVIEWS . (($reviews['count'] > 0) ? ' (' . $reviews['count'] . ')' : ''), 'comment', tep_href_link(FILENAME_PRODUCT_REVIEWS, tep_get_all_get_params())); ?></td>
```

That is the script I am using to create the review button, but I would like to insert an image into it. Any ideas would be most appreciative.

This is the code for tep_draw_button() function:

```
function tep_draw_button($title = null, $icon = null, $link = null, $priority = null, $params = null) {
static $button_counter = 1;

$types = array('submit', 'button', 'reset');

if ( !isset($params['type']) ) {
  $params['type'] = 'submit';
}

if ( !in_array($params['type'], $types) ) {
  $params['type'] = 'submit';
}

if ( ($params['type'] == 'submit') && isset($link) ) {
  $params['type'] = 'button';
}

if (!isset($priority)) {
  $priority = 'secondary';
}

$button = '<span class="tdbLink">';

if ( ($params['type'] == 'button') && isset($link) ) {
  $button .= '<a id="tdb' . $button_counter . '" href="' . $link . '"';

  if ( isset($params['newwindow']) ) {
    $button .= ' target="_blank"';
  }
} else {
  $button .= '<button id="tdb' . $button_counter . '" type="' . tep_output_string($params['type']) . '"';
}

if ( isset($params['params']) ) {
  $button .= ' ' . $params['params'];
}

$button .= '>' . $title;

if ( ($params['type'] == 'button') && isset($link) ) {
  $button .= '</a>';
} else {
  $button .= '</button>';
}

$button .= '</span><script type="text/javascript">$("#tdb' . $button_counter . '").button(';

$args = array();

if ( isset($icon) ) {
  if ( !isset($params['iconpos']) ) {
    $params['iconpos'] = 'left';
  }

  if ( $params['iconpos'] == 'left' ) {
    $args[] = 'icons:{primary:"ui-icon-' . $icon . '"}';
  } else {
    $args[] = 'icons:{secondary:"ui-icon-' . $icon . '"}';
  }
}

if (empty($title)) {
  $args[] = 'text:false';
}

if (!empty($args)) {
  $button .= '{' . implode(',', $args) . '}';
}

$button .= ').addClass("ui-priority-' . $priority . '").parent().removeClass("tdbLink");</script>';

$button_counter++;

return $button;
}
?>
```

Comment: I think we would need to know what the open-source frame work is, or at least a snippet of code for the `tep_draw_button()` function to be able to help you.

Comment: dig into the source, its open now... ;)

Comment: the open source in use is oscommerce. the code for the tep_draw button() function is shown:

Comment: Did you give mine a try?  Is there anything that you need tweaked?  I'm not a huge fan of investing a lot of time into an answer and never getting a response... :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably override the style by using some css:

```
#your_button_id{ background: url(); height: x; width: x; etc...  }
.your_button_class{ background: url(); height: x; width: x; etc...  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

To call the button, use the function with the parameters as they are below:

```
$image['src'] = 'http://yoururl.com/image.jpg'; // Image Source
$image['height'] = 600;  // Image Height
$image['width'] = 300;   // Image Width

tep_draw_button(IMAGE_BUTTON_REVIEWS . (($reviews['count'] > 0) ? ' (' . $reviews['count'] . ')' : ''), 'comment', tep_href_link(FILENAME_PRODUCT_REVIEWS, tep_get_all_get_params()), null, null, $image);
```

Then modify the tep_draw_button function like so.  If you have an image source in the function parameter, the image will be placed in as a link rather than as a button.

```
<?
function tep_draw_button($title = null, $icon = null, $link = null, $priority = null, $params = null, $image = null) {
static $button_counter = 1;

if($image != null){

    $button = '<span class="tdbLink">';
    $button .= '<a id="tdb' . $button_counter . '" href="' . $link . '"';
    $button .= '><img src="'. $image['src'] .'"';
    if(is_numeric($image['height'])) $button .= ' height="'.$image['height'].'"';
    if(is_numeric($image['width'])) $button .= ' width="'.$image['width'].'"';
    $button .= 'alt="'.$title.'" /></a></span>';

}else{

$types = array('submit', 'button', 'reset');

if ( !isset($params['type']) ) {
  $params['type'] = 'submit';
}

if ( !in_array($params['type'], $types) ) {
  $params['type'] = 'submit';
}

if ( ($params['type'] == 'submit') && isset($link) ) {
  $params['type'] = 'button';
}

if (!isset($priority)) {
  $priority = 'secondary';
}

$button = '<span class="tdbLink">';

if ( ($params['type'] == 'button') && isset($link) ) {
  $button .= '<a id="tdb' . $button_counter . '" href="' . $link . '"';

  if ( isset($params['newwindow']) ) {
    $button .= ' target="_blank"';
  }
} else {
  $button .= '<button id="tdb' . $button_counter . '" type="' . tep_output_string($params['type']) . '"';
}

if ( isset($params['params']) ) {
  $button .= ' ' . $params['params'];
}

$button .= '>' . $title;

if ( ($params['type'] == 'button') && isset($link) ) {
  $button .= '</a>';
} else {
  $button .= '</button>';
}

$button .= '</span><script type="text/javascript">$("#tdb' . $button_counter . '").button(';

$args = array();

if ( isset($icon) ) {
  if ( !isset($params['iconpos']) ) {
    $params['iconpos'] = 'left';
  }

  if ( $params['iconpos'] == 'left' ) {
    $args[] = 'icons:{primary:"ui-icon-' . $icon . '"}';
  } else {
    $args[] = 'icons:{secondary:"ui-icon-' . $icon . '"}';
  }
}

if (empty($title)) {
  $args[] = 'text:false';
}

if (!empty($args)) {
  $button .= '{' . implode(',', $args) . '}';
}

$button .= ').addClass("ui-priority-' . $priority . '").parent().removeClass("tdbLink");</script>';

$button_counter++;
}

return $button;
}
?>
```

Let me know if this works, or if you need it tweaked at all.  It's hard for me to test since I don't have an oscommerce instance on my machine to test on.